# Aligning <button=type> to center with .CSS

Tags: html, css

```css
.signupH {
 background-color:#9FADBC;
 color:white;
 border-top-left-radius:10px;
 border-top-right-radius:10px;
 width:300px;
 height:18px;
 font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
 font-weight:3px;
 text-align:center;
 margin-top:-10px;
 margin:auto;
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 bottom:20;
 right:0;
    padding:10px;
 }

.signupback {
 background-color:#55789e;
 width:300px;
 height:210px;
    margin:auto;
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 bottom:0;
 right:0;
    padding:10px;
 webkit-border-radius: 10px;
 khtml-border-radius: 10px; 
 moz-border-radius: 10px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 }
```

```html
<body bgcolor="#215698">

 <div class="signupback">
 <table>
   <center><div class="signupH">
    Graphicx | Sign up
   </div></center>
  <br>
 <form role="form" action="login-post.php" method="POST">
 <table align="middle">
 <tr>
 <td>
  Username:
 </td>
 <td>
      
      <input id="username" type="text" value="username" 
      onfocus="this.value = this.value=='username'?'':this.value;" 
      onblur="this.value = this.value==''?'username':this.value;", >
      
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>
  Email:
 </td>
 <td>
      <input id="email" type="text" value="email" 
      onfocus="this.value = this.value=='email'?'':this.value;" 
      onblur="this.value = this.value==''?'email':this.value;", >
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>
  Password:
 </td>
 <td>
      <input id="password" type="password" value="password" 
      onfocus="this.value = this.value=='password'?'':this.value;" 
      onblur="this.value = this.value==''?'password':this.value;", >
 </td>
 </tr>
   
     <center><button type="submit" class="button">Sign up</button></center>

 </form>
 </div>
 </table>
  <br> 
    
       
</body>
```

The button gets put at the top of the form, i need it to go under the Username, Email and Password text fields. Please can someone help me with this error?

I need to move the button below the text fields but still has to be within the form attribute to connect it with my SQL Databases.

Help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try putting it in another set of table row tags:

```
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>        
                <center><button type="submit" class="button">Sign up</button></center>
</td>
</tr>

</form>
```

...or make it a block element in CSS by giving it the following attribute:

```
style="display:block"
```

Answer (score 0):

I just moved the html of the class "center" below the html from the inputs and it worked. Your snippet's code doesn't match what you linked here in the question.